# Why under WIFI I can see $_SESSION variables and under sim network they don't exist?

Tags: php, session, networking, mobile, wifi

I'm developing a login page using PHP and Js.
When the user load this page a call to a php file gives back a token that is saved in my $_SESSION.
On my laptop, using Chrome, everything works fine.
On my mobile, using Chrome in Incognito mode and under WIFI, everything works fine.
On my mobile, when I switch to sim network, I cannot see anymore any $_SESSION variables.

Here below there are two images, one under WIFI and the second under mobile network:

[Example under WIFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJgh.png)
[Example under Mobile Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC1jm.png)

```
//login page

<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
echo json_encode($_SESSION);

$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
session_write_close();

$url = "www.dominio.com/page_token.php";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

ob_start();
$token = curl_exec ($curl);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($curl);
unset($ch);
?>
```

```
//page_token.php

<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();

$_SESSION['fast_token'] = generate_token(30);
echo $_SESSION['fast_token'];
?>
```

Does anyone have some ideas about this trouble?

Comment: you need to show some parts of code as well to make someone able to find the cause of your problem

Comment: Hello,  in fact you still can see the session array, however, it is empty.

Comment: @IronyStack I added some code, nothing really complex, just a curl call for the token